# How to assert if this text contain at least one words from one statement in cypress

Tags: javascript, cypress

For example

```js
cy.get('.stitle').contains("learning table",{ matchCase: false })
```

This statement will pass the test if `.stitle` has the full text of "learning table",
but what I really want is `.stitle` either has "learning just", or "table just". And so both can pass the test

because I want it to be reusable for any statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expression to do so, here is a quick example:

```js
cy.get(".stitle").contains(/(learning|table)/i);
```

This matches:

```html
<p class="stitle">
  learning Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
  Dolor, in nulla dolores vero autem cum vitae. Eaque ipsum, numquam, ea
  nam iste a quaerat excepturi facilis praesentium repellendus laudantium
  blanditiis.
</p>
```

or

```html
<p class="stitle">
  Lorem ipsum, dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Dolor, in
  nulla dolores table vero autem cum vitae. Eaque ipsum, numquam, ea nam
  iste a quaerat excepturi facilis praesentium repellendus laudantium
  blanditiis.
</p>
```